# User agent stylesheet setting script code to display none

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to get a code generated by Crowdriff to display a gallery on a page and it is being blocked with css that I am not defining as display none. I'm not sure where this is coming from as I haven't set it anywhere to display none.

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPmeU.jpg)

Here is the page where it should be showing:

https://www.orillialakecountry.ca/test-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

Script tags are never displayed. These are used to import and execute javascript files.

In the javascript a HTML element is probably targeted in which it tries to inject it's HTML.